# How to make sure the order of the buttons are same using cypress

Tags: cypress

I have a use case
I have three buttons Accept,Decline and Cookie Choices.
I click an option and after that when these buttons show-up,
I want to make sure the order of these buttons is exactly the same Accept,Decline and Cookie Choices
How do we automate this scenario in Cypress to make sure the order of these buttons is same.

Comment: Show us the HTML of the buttons.

Answer (score 3):

Select all the 3 buttons using. For example by placing a `data-testid` on them

```html
<button data-testid="cookie-btn">Accept</button>
<button data-testid="cookie-btn">Decline</button>
<button data-testid="cookie-btn">Cookie choices</button>
```

then use [first](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/first) and [next](https://commands) to go through them sequentially. For example

```js
cy.get('[data-testid="cookie-btn"]')
  .should("have.length", 3)
  .first()
  .should("have.text", "Accept")
  .next()
  .should("have.text", "Decline")
  .next()
  .should("have.text", "Cookie choices");
```

Comment: They all have different <button id as tags.
Hence when i use next and last it will not work.

Comment: I just observed one thing,
The button has below attribute
style="order: 1;"
How we can capture this attribute

Comment: I got it
 cy.get(button_acceptall).invoke('css','order').should('equal','1')
 cy.get(button_cookiechoices).invoke('css','order').should('equal','2')
 cy.get(button_declineall).invoke('css','order').should('equal','3')